# Matrix transformation notation

Tags: matrices, notation, transformation

I have a question about a transformation of a matrix. Lets say we have the following matrix

$
M =
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
 4 & 3  \\
 4 & 3  \\
 \end{array} } \right]
$

Then I want to transform all numbers in the matrix with the following function:

$f(x) = (x - 4)^2 + 2x -4$

What would be the correct notation for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand your question, but: what's wrong with this?

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
f(4) & f(3) \\\
f(4) & f(3)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

More generally, if you have a matrix $(a^i_j)$, you could write the resulting matrix as $(f(a^i_j))$.

Comment: Okay thanks, basically that's what I had I my head only I wasn't to sure if it was the proper notation xD

Answer (score 2):

Could use the "Hadamard Product"... I don't know whether there is a consistently accepted notation for such a product, however a few examples [here](https://planetmath.org/HadamardProduct) and on Wikipedia seem to use an open circle.

In that sense, your expression would take the form

$(M-4O)\circ(M-4O)+2M-4O$ where $O= \left(  \begin{array} {cc} 1 &1 \\ 1&1 \end{array}  \right) $

In MATLAB, use .* for element-wise multiplication.

There are probably other possibilities.